# Create a redux middleware retry function for expired sessions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In my app, I'm running every request trough an api middleware. I'm trying to create a middleware retry function, when requests with [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) are happening and have an expired token. Here is my current API middleware:

```
const apiMiddleware = ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
  next(action);
  // creating request data and params

  const retryRequest = () => {
    // refresh tokens with method: dispatch(getTokens());
    // retry initial request
  };

  axios({
    method,
    url,
    headers,
    [dataOrParams]: data,
  })
    .then(({ data: apiData }) => {
      dispatch(onSuccess(apiData));
    })
    .catch(error => {
      if (withToken && error.response.status === 401) {
        retryRequest();
      }
      return dispatch(apiError(label, error));
    })
};

export default apiMiddleware;
```

When I call `retryRequest()` method the `getTokens()` request starts, but at the same time starts the initial requests, and Redux is not yet updated with the new refresh token, and the requests fail again, because `getTokens()` is not finished.

I understand that I'm doing it the wrong way, what other solutions I can try? So that first the request `getTokens()` is called and finished than the initial request can go on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can make retryRequest() and the catch function async, you can use

```
if(withToken && error.reponse.status === 401)
  await retryRequest();
return dispatch(apiError(label, error));
```

If you cant, just return the promise from retry request and

```
if(withToken && error.response.status === 401)
  return retryRequest().then(_=> dispatch(apiError(label, error)))
return dispatch(apiError(label, error))
```

You could also use an axios interceptor, this is the one I use in my most recent projects

```js
api.interceptors.response.use(
  function (response) {
    response.data = parseResponseData(response.data);
    return response;
  },
  async function (error) {
    if (!error.response)
      Ant.message.error('Não foi possivel se conectar com o servidor');
    else if (
      error.response.status === 500 &&
      window.location.pathname !== '/erro/500'
    ) {
      if ((error.config.method as string).toLowerCase() === 'get')
        navigate('/erro/500');
      else
        Ant.message.error(
          'Desculpe, parece que algo deu errado no servidor.',
        );
    } else if (error.response.status === 401) {
      let request = error.config;
      const auth = localStorage.getItem('auth');
      let refreshToken = auth && JSON.parse(auth)['refreshToken'];
      var authService = new AuthService();
      return await authService
        .refresh(refreshToken)
        .then(async (resp) => {
          store.dispatch(login(resp.data));
          let axiosInstance = axios.create();
          intercept(axiosInstance);
          return await axiosInstance.request(request);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          if (
            window.location.pathname !== '/login' &&
            (!e.response || e.response.status === 401)
          )
            navigate('/login');
        });
    }
    return error.response;
  },
);
```

It has worked pretty well so far.